# Hadoop : Is it possible edit a File within hdfs?

Tags: java, hadoop

I want java code to split a csv file (in HDFS) into 3 files without moving it to local machine. This has to be done within HDFS.

Comment: people are here will able to help when you provide what you had tried and what problem you are facing in that. Please provide some your Map/Reduce or Pig UDF script code which you are trying for your task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to read some documentations ... [Here](http://www.mund-consulting.com/Blog/Posts/file-operations-in-HDFS-using-java.aspx) is a nice post and you will probably found out the solution by yourself, it's only a java program :)

Comment: You're welcome :) mark the post as answered if you've found your answer in this link

Answer (score 0):

Need more details about your question.
Do you just want to split the file into 3 files with random size or is there some business requirement that you have on which you have to split the file.

However whatever your scenario is you can write a Mapper alone and save the output of the mapper to a file or you can write a Pig script to do the same.

Sample Pig Script(Assuming that you already have Pig installed on your machine)

Let's say you input file is the one given below and is saved as InputData.txt

```
Shabbir           Khan             9314573259     Bangalore        Engineer

Manish            Sharma        8882148796     Gurgaon           Lecturer

Mahesh           Kumar          8521548932     Noida                Business

Sampath         Reddy           8547987412     Hyderabad         Engineer

Mohan            Reddy           9256458798     Hyderabad         Professor
```

Pig script to load and store the file based on a condition that I need only the records with City as Hyderabad.

```
A = LOAD 'InputData.txt' using PigStorage (‘\t’) as (FName: chararray, LName: chararray, MobileNo: chararray, City: chararray, Profession: chararray);
FilteredLst = FILTER A BY City='Hyderabad';
store FilteredLst '/user/output';
```

Comment: My input file is already in a folder in hdfs. can this be done within hdfs?

Comment: Mapper tasks or Pig scripts can run only within HDFS. It wont work on files on the local file system.

Comment: The inputfile is the file I got as a output from a Mapreduce program. Can I use pig script to do this? Please guide me how to do this

Comment: Yes yo can definitely do this. In the above code that I have pasted. Replace InputData.txt with the exact location and file name of the Map Reduce output file and add your filter condition. Learn more commands of PigScripting to better suit you needs from [here](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.8.1/piglatin_ref2.html#SPLIT)

Comment: My input file is of this format:
Shabbir           Khan             9314573259     Bangalore        Engineer Manish            Sharma        8882148796     Gurgaon           Lecturer Mahesh           Kumar          8521548932     Noida                Business Sampath         Reddy           8547987412     Hyderabad         Engineer Mohan            Reddy           9256458798     Hyderabad         Professor

First I have to split this this. What to do now?